# Developing EVP_CIPHER for OpenSSL 3

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

I am currently learning openssl cms. I want to use **CMS_encrypt_ex()** to create and return a CMS AuthEnvelopedData structure the use a modified ECIES EVP_CIPHER.
I was wondering if anyone knew of any good examples, discussions that can help answer some of these questions or at least give me a toehold into things?

Thank you!!!

`CMS_ContentInfo *CMS_encrypt_ex(STACK_OF(X509) *certs, BIO *in, const EVP_CIPHER *cipher, unsigned int flags, OSSL_LIB_CTX *libctx, const char *propq);`

I tried many times, but I failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.